# Unable to connect with MS SQL Server management studio 2008 r2 with Liferay 6.2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, liferay, liferay-6

I am unable to solve this issue. Here I am using SQL SERVER management studion 2008 r2 and I want to connect with this to Liferay 6.2. SQL server is in my system means local and windows authentication I am using to connect so no password but every time I get an error

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:257)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:311)
    ... 10 more
10:36:53,951 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->9tPNsR91]-HelperThread-#8][BasicResourcePool:1851] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@654f1b6d -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
```

please help me
thanks 
asif aftab

Answer (score 0):

First thanks for all for your support finally I got solution. Its took my ample amount of time but I got solution.
First brief description

1) I am using Liferay 6.2.

2) I want to connect with MS SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 r2 (This is similar to MS SQL Server but with  lots of limitations).

3) SQL Server is present in my system(local).
Error: That I got is 
[b]IOExcpetion: refuse to connect[/b].

Now the solution is

Configuration of MS SQL Server connection in portal-ext.properties file

```
  jdbc.default.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
  jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/lportal
  jdbc.default.username=sa (this is default login name )
  jdbc.default.password=your password
```

The main thing is we have to change the port of tcp/ip to 1433 the default port of MS SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 r2.

Start menu of windows then

**
1. MS SQL Server 2008 r2 -> configuration tool -> SQL Server configuration manager -> yes(pop up)
  then on extreme left select there is a tree structure then

1. SQL Server network configuration -> Protocols for sql server -> rt click on tcp/ip and enable it
2. Double click on tcp/ip then one pop up will display
3. Select IP Adrees tab, lots of IPAdress block you can see and inside this block you can see one label IP Address having value 127.0.0.1 then change its tcp port value to 1433.**
   5.Check also that the tcp is enable or not, if not then please enable it and also change the value of IP4 label having ip val is 192.168... tcp port value to 1433.

Hence try to connect, this time this will work.

Thanks

asif aftab